# Why are are these functions not returned?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Currently I am reading eloquent javascript and am at the section about higher order functions and was wondering why in this example the writer doesn't use `return then()` Or `return body(i)`

```
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) then();
}
function repeat(times, body) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
  unless(n % 2, function() {
    console.log(n, "is even");
  });
});
// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even`
```

Comment: `return then()` would be possible, but it's not necessary. `return body(i)` would be wrong because it would immediately exit the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: Because it is expected that the type of `then` is `void -> void` - the `else` block returns `undefined` as well. Of course, in a *pure* language these wouldn't be too helpful.

Comment: @Pointy makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the given examples the functions are executed for their side effects, not the value they compute.  Thus, there is nothing useful to return.  In hard core functional programming this kind of pattern would generally be avoided as the idea is to have minimal or no effects, but to only compute values.  There are exceptions, mainly in the realm of IO, which is fundamentally effectual and necessary for most useful applications.